# FINDSTR only folders with specific name

Tags: for-loop, directory, findstr

I have a large folder structure with specific names. I'm searching for string "**test**" in files starting with name "**sifre-**" in all folders and subfolders and returning the result as full path.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /b /s /m "test" "E:\sifre-*.txt"') do set RESULT=%%a
```

This command is working great for now. There is alway only one possible result.

Now I would like to write a command to find the same string in folders and subfolders **BUT** only  those with specific name "**ID**".

Thanx